# GC.collect is not releasing memory

Tags: .net, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am having an issue where the service application starts out at 16k and over 4 days gets to 3mg in memory.

The application cycles over and over again and waits x secs before it cycles again and the memory should release on every cycle. It looks like the memory just increases after x amount of cycles but never falls back down as I thought it would.

I am positive I am not doing something correctly but I am not sure what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I used

```
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Config
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class EDIService
    Implements IDisposable

    Private Shared ReadOnly _log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(EDIService))

    Dim strStorageFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
    Dim strWorkFolder As String = strStorageFolder & "\EDIService"
    Dim strLogFolder As String = strWorkFolder & "\Log"

    Public MsSQLConn As SqlConnection
    Dim Comm As New Onling.clsSQLExecutes

    Dim objDSMS As DataSet
    Dim objDTMS As DataTable
    Dim objDSMT As DataSet
    Dim objDTMT As DataTable
    Dim objDSP As DataSet
    Dim objDTP As DataTable

    Private stopping As Boolean
    Private stoppedEvent As ManualResetEvent


    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        'Init the log for net settings (must have in 4.0 Framework)
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
        Me.stopping = False
        Me.stoppedEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)

        StartUp()

    End Sub
```

The onStart

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Log a service start message to the Application log.
        _log.Info("EDI Service in OnStart.")

        ' Queue the main service function for execution in a worker thread.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf ServiceWorkerThread))
    End Sub
```

The ServiceWorkerThread

```
Private Sub ServiceWorkerThread(ByVal state As Object)
    ' Periodically check if the service is stopping.
    Do While Not Me.stopping
        CheckForFiles()
        _log.Info("Sent to garbage collector")
        'GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        'GC.Collect()
        'GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        'GC.Collect()
        'Dispose(True)
        'GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        ' Perform main service function here...
        _log.Info("Sleeping for " & My.Settings.TimerMilliseconds / 1000 & " seconds")
        Thread.Sleep(My.Settings.TimerMilliseconds)  ' Simulate some lengthy operations.
    Loop

    ' Signal the stopped event.
    Me.stoppedEvent.Set()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

End Sub
```

Comment: 4mb is not a lot of RAM so don't worry about that. You really shouldn't have a cached SQL connection `Public MsSQLConn As SqlConnection` instead create it when you need it and dispose with `Using`

Comment: Most of my applications are 250k or less usually, but I will convert my connection to using and try that avenue. I am using a class that I created back when ADO.NET was introduced. Thanks for the input @Charlieface